# rc.local does not run program with parameters correctly

Tags: linux, rc

I am on Armbian.

I am trying to run hyperion-v4l2 in /etc/rc.local (please it is not important why for now) with these parameters:
Code:

```
/home/user/hyperion/build/bin/hyperion-v4l2 --device /dev/video0 --video-standard PAL --width 720 --height 576 --crop-top 10 --crop-bottom 10 --crop-left 24 --crop-right 24 --frame-decimator 1 --size-decimator 4 --red-threshold 0.2 --green-threshold 0.4 --blue-threshold 1.0
```

(before v4l2 I am executing sudo /home/user/hyperion/build/bin/hyperiond /home/user/hyperion.config.json)
But it does not take crop parameters in effect (important for blackborder detection) of hyperion-v4l2.
I tried to put the whole command in sh and python script (subprocess) but it is the same, in rc.local crop parameters are omitted, no idea why. BUT when I execute the same SH or Python script when I log in via my user, it works correctly.

What can be wrong? In rc.local and all executed scripts via rc.local it does not take crop parameters in effect. Maybe the line with parameters is very long, but I don't understand it because manually the same scripts work correctly.

UPDATE: After several trial and errors I found out, probably, it is related to  THIS   sudo /home/user/hyperion/build/bin/hyperiond /home/user/hyperion.config.json. Because when I run this script via rc.local and then manually hyperion-v4l2, then behaviour is the same.

Comment: What does /var/log/messages and /var/log/syslog say? Usually it will log the events when the scripts are ran?

Comment: @ryekayo, in logs everything seems to be ok.

Comment: @Christopher, I removed sudo already. I don't know what is "requiretty" or script with "-c" parameter.

Comment: UPDATE: After several trial and errors I found out, probably, it is related to  THIS   sudo /home/user/hyperion/build/bin/hyperiond /home/user/hyperion.config.json. Because when I run this script via rc.local and then manually hyperion-v4l2, then behaviour is the same.